# How can I limit the number of selected items in a radTreeListView?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, telerik, radtreeview

How can I limit the number of selected (checked) items in a `radTreeListView`? Say after a user has selected (checked) 5 items, a stop them from checking/selecting more items in c#.

Which event to I need to handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achivement:

```
 private void radTreeListView_SelectionChanging(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (radTreeListView.SelectedItems.Count >= 5 && e.AddedItems.Count>0)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```